# Symfony task on the hosting

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, task

I have task:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

class GroupCheckTask extends sfBaseTask
{
  protected function configure()
  {
    // // add your own arguments here
    // $this->addArguments(array(
    //   new sfCommandArgument('my_arg', sfCommandArgument::REQUIRED, 'My argument'),
    // ));

      $this->addOptions(array(
      new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name'),
      new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'dev'),
      new sfCommandOption('connection', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The connection name', 'doctrine'),
      // add your own options here
    ));

    $this->namespace        = '';
    $this->name             = 'GroupCheck';
    $this->briefDescription = '';
    $this->detailedDescription = <<<EOF
The [GroupCheck|INFO] task does things.
Call it with:

  [php symfony GroupCheck|INFO]
EOF;
  }

  protected function execute($arguments = array(), $options = array())
  {

    $databaseManager = new sfDatabaseManager($this->configuration);
    $connection = $databaseManager->getDatabase($options['connection'])->getConnection();

    // add your code here



    $users=  Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUserProfile')->getUserDelay() ;


       foreach($users as $sfGuardUserProfile)
       {
          $users_id =$sfGuardUserProfile-> getUserId();

          $userForChange =  Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUserGroup')->getUserForChange($users_id) ;

          foreach($userForChange as $sfGuardUserGroup)
       {

            $sfGuardUserGroup->setSfGuardGroup(Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardGroup')-        >findOneByName('basic'))->save();

       }

       }
  }
}
```

And in my localhost all works fine, but it is not work in hosting. What is the correct way to run task on hosting from cron tab?

Comment: What isn't working specifically? How are you running the task on your host?

Comment: Well in my localhost all works fine,so I run task in localhost from NetBeans.But, I do not now how my manager run it on server...Is it possible that it work on localhost , but can not work in server?

Comment: Why don't you run it on the server and see?

Comment: I have only ftp access(I can not run it on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you dont need put the line `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');`

second, write a **namespace** for your task is a good practice

third, you need the the a php file like:

```
<?php
  /* /path/to/file.php */
  chdir("/the/path/in/your/host/to/symfony/project");
  exec("symfony your_namespace:GroupCheck");
?>
```

last, you can put this file in your crontab

```
00 59 23 * * php /path/to/file.php
```

Comment: `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');` - it is work for me.I made it, but it was few month ago :) Thanks!